# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

I need to give validation for every edit text of main XML and save button is also scrolling and date is showing in Text view of date,after save that person details should be added to the next screen at top of the List View ,already List view had five defalut person details,i am unable to do this please help me,in List View every items should consists update and delete button ,click on update dailog should open and need to be edited in dailog,delete means delete person details from the listview.

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Name:"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_name1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:hint="Enter Your Name"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Email:"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:hint="Enter Your Mail"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_phoneno"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Phone No:"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_phoneno"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:hint="Enter your Contact No"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="DOB:"
                    android:textSize="15dp"

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/datepicker1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp">

                </Button>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_qualification"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Qualification"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_qualification"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:hint="Enter Your Qualification"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_time"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Time:"
                    android:textSize="15dp"

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/timepicker1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp">

                </Button>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15dp">

            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout
```

> Person.java

```
package com.example.android.persondetails;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String contactno;
    private String email;
    private String qualification;
    private String datepicker;
    private String timepicker;



    public Person(String name, String contactno, String email, String qualification, String datepicker, String timepicker) {
        this.name = name;
        this.contactno = contactno;
        this.qualification=qualification;
        this.datepicker=datepicker;
        this.email=email;
        this.timepicker=timepicker;


    }

    public String getName() {
        return name == null ? "" : name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String  getContactno() {
        return contactno;
    }

    public void  setContactno(String contactno){
        this.contactno=contactno;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getQualification() {
        return qualification;
    }

    public String getDatepicker() {
        return datepicker;
    }

    public String getTimepicker() {
        return timepicker;
    }
}
```

> SecondActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.persondetails;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Calendar.AM;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvContact;
    private Button addBtn,dleBtn;
    private PersonListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Person> mPersonList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

       ArrayList<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        dleBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
        lvContact = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        addMethod();
        setAdapter();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text;
        text = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
        String text1 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_EMAIL);
        String text3 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        String text4 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DOB);
        String text5 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TIME);
        String text2 = (String)intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_QUALIFICATION);

        Log.d("PersonDetails", text + " " + text1 + "" + text2 + "" + text3 + "" + text4 + "" + text5);

    }

    private void addMethod() {

        mPersonList.add(new Person("Narendra", "83330072", "narendraprasad616@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1996", "5-30 AM"));
        mPersonList.add(new Person("Banu", "715452", "naredra@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1996", "5-45 AM"));
        mPersonList.add(new Person("Kalyan", "83330072", "narendraprad616@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1998", "5-30 AM"));
        mPersonList.add(new Person("Teja", "8775564", "narendraprasa16@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1990", "5-30 AM"));
        mPersonList.add(new Person("Manu", "86423", "narendraprad616@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1996", "5-30 AM"));

    }


    private void setAdapter() {
        adapter = new PersonListAdapter(SecondActivity.this, mPersonList);
        lvContact.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.persondetails">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> PersonListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.persondetails;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class PersonListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Person> mPersonList;

    PersonListAdapter(Context mContext, List<Person> mPersonList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPersonList = mPersonList;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPersonList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mPersonList.get(position);
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, parent, false);
            holder.tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name1);
            holder.tv_contactno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phoneno);
            holder.tv_email=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            holder.tv_dob=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
            holder.tv_qualification=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qualification);
            holder.tv_time=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_name.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_contactno.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getContactno());
        holder.tv_email.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.tv_dob.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getDatepicker());
        holder.tv_qualification.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getQualification());
        holder.tv_time.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getTimepicker());
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_name;
        TextView tv_email;
        TextView tv_contactno;
        TextView tv_dob;
        TextView tv_qualification;
        TextView tv_time;

    }

}
```

> second_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_name1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_phoneno"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name1"
        android:text="contactno"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_phoneno"
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_email"
        android:text="DOB"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_qualification"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_dob"
        android:text="Qualification"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_qualification"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Upadate"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/update"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Person">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.persondetails;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog; import android.app.TimePickerDialog; import android.content.Intent; import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat; import android.os.Build; import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.DatePicker; import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.ParseException; import java.util.Calendar; import java.util.Date;

import static android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL; import static android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER; import static android.os.DropBoxManager.EXTRA_TIME; import static android.security.KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_NAME";
    public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_EMAIL";
    public static final String EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER";
    public static final String EXTRA_DOB = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_DOB";
    public static final String EXTRA_QUALIFICATION = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_QUALIFICATION";
    public static final String EXTRA_TIME = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_TIME";
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5, textView6;
    EditText editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute, format;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_phoneno);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_qualification);
        textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.datepicker1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timepicker1);


        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == button1) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            format = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            textView4.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == button2) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            format = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
            final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {


                            String time = selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute;

                            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                            Date date = null;
                            try {
                                date = fmt.parse(time);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

                            String formattedTime = fmtOut.format(date);

                            textView6.setText(formattedTime);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }


            if (v == button3) {
                EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name1);
                String text = editText1.getText().toString();
                EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
                String text1 = editText2.getText().toString();
                EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_phoneno);
                String number = String.valueOf(editText3.getText().toString());
                Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.datepicker1);
                String number1 = button1.getText().toString();
                EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_qualification);
                String text2 = editText4.getText().toString();
                Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timepicker1);
                String number2 = button2.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, text);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, text1);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, number);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DOB, number1);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_QUALIFICATION, text2);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, number2);
                startActivity(intent);

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Replace `ArrayList<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();` line with `mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();`

Comment: ok after that@ ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: Hi, ρяσѕρєя K My problem is i was unable to add defalut arraylist data to items of list view after clicking save button app is crashing ,i want to add person details in top of list view ,every item should have one delete and update button ,delete means it would be deleted,update means one dialog should open like in main xml and it should be edited and save person details to item please help me@ ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicated question for the link it is saying. That is a general question and answer for how a null pointer may occur. But this question about the implementation section and posted to check logical flow in the code and that is why everyone is trying to find the bug. So though both beloging to nullPointerException but are different query at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed one major issue as mentioned below in comment.

```
    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvContact;
    private Button addBtn,dleBtn;
    private PersonListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Person> mPersonList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

        //Error as creating a new object mPersonList which is local to onCreate()
        //Finally class variable mPersonList will be null still.

        //ArrayList<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>(); //Logical Error 

        //Solution: Use class variable instead of creating a new variable. So, just replace the above commented line with below one.
        mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);

        ..... continue
    }
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: where shall i update @Hari N jha,help me

Comment: I have sent the code and added my comment. You simply need to update a single line in SecondActivity onCreate(). Just change the line where I have commented Logical Error with the line "mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();" which is just next to the comment line. By doing this you class variable will become not null arraylist. Let me know if you have further confusion.

Comment: I have updated my comment a bit also for your better understanding.

Comment: thanks and i saved it,have you understand what task do i need to complete@Hari N Jha

Comment: I am not sure whether you have made any comment on the issue is solved or asking anything else. However if it solved your issue of nullPointerException then accept the answer so that it would help other to trust the solution. Thanks.

Comment: yes it has done your answer is right

Comment: Then please accept the answer so that it will help other to trust.

Comment: As a reminder, it would add trust to other users by accepting the answer.